# TCP connections retains even sessions terminates

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2016, port, tcp

We have client/server application running in our environment, we are experiencing an issue that single client having multiple connections to the server, although, there is only one instance is running on the client machine.

[image]

We have server running Windows 2016 standard and clients are running Windows 10.

On the other note even we are killing the process manually from Task manager and terminating the application despite connections being retained. We have tried clearing DNS cache and renewing IP as well as restarting both server and client still issue persists. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's likely that understanding this might require knowledge on the internal operation of this application.

Comment: Hi @EsaJokinen - We have this application installed with multiple client only this specific client experiencing this issue, therefore, we thought it could be more of system and network issue.

Comment: Your problem is not on the IP or DNS layers, so nothing there will help. The problem is at the TCP layer, the connections are not closed fully. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#/media/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed_new.svg   You can probably configure the timeouts, but looking at the application behaviour is probably a better path top success.